AuraException when running test code for 2gp managed package version create
I was created a unlocked package successfully, and I tried create a managed package with same codeset. But when I try to create package version for 2gp managed package, apex test failed with AuraException.
Here are two code set have problem.
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String doQuery(String query){
        String result = '';
        try {
            map<String, Object> queryMap = (map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(query);
            system.debug(queryMap);
            String  queryString  = (String) queryMap.get('query');
            Integer pageSize     = (Integer) queryMap.get('pageSize');
            Integer pageNumber   = (Integer) queryMap.get('pageNum');

            String records = '';
            PageReference queryPage = Page.CustomQuery;

            queryPage.getParameters().put('queryString', queryString);
            queryPage.getParameters().put('pageSize', String.valueOf(pageSize));
            queryPage.getParameters().put('pageNumber', String.valueOf(pageNumber));

            if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                records = '[]';
            } else {
                records = queryPage.getContent().toString();
            }

            // wrap records
            map<String, Object> resultMap = new map<String, Object>();
            resultMap.put('records', records);
            resultMap.put('count', '100');
            result = JSON.serialize(resultMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }


and
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean updateListview(String listview){
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            if (!Schema.sObjectType.CustomListView__c.isCreateable() 
                || !Schema.sObjectType.CustomListView__c.isUpdateable() ) {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Not permitted');
            }
            system.debug(listview);
            CustomListView__c cl = (CustomListView__c) JSON.deserializeStrict(listview, CustomListView__c.class);

            upsert cl;
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }


What is differenct between unlocked and managed package?
How can I handle this problems?
Thanks and regards,

What is the exception's message + stack trace?

@kurunve Just 'script thrown exception', I just recognize missing namespace for test code's query string.

Does the exception mention the namespace explicitly or have you found that some other way? The distinction between managed and unlocked packages is that the packages for an unlocked package aren't validated on package creation, but rather on installation, whereas a managed package is validated against a scratch org on creation. You'd likely hit the same error when you tried installing the unlocked package.

@CallumMacErlich I found some namespace related syntax errors from caller function. that function assign sobject field as string value. this string value also need to patch with new value with namespace prefix. Thanks advise... ^^
